# kendo grid data depending on another kendo grid results UI for Asp.Net MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I Have two Kendo Grids (UI for Asp.Net MVC) on my page. The first grid gets results from database using an action method of a controller which is bound at grid initialization(I guess). The second grid should get the results of a column from first grid and pass as parameters to second grid which should pass these to action method of another controller bound to second grid. I tried to use autobind(false) but has no use. Please suggest.

Comment: What about: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy

Comment: Hook into the [change event](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/events) of the datagrid, fetch the selected id and pass it along to the next grid. The link in the sample gives you everything you need, but without any code examples of what you've accomplished so far, there's not much more to advise on.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**VIEW**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.TestModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.ID);
        columns.Bound(e => e.Name);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Home"))
     )
     .Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))
      .Selectable(selectable => selectable
            .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))

)

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.ChildModel>()
    .Name("ChildGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.ChildID);
        columns.Bound(e => e.ChildName);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetChildData", "Home").Data("GetData"))
     )
)

<script>
    var ID = 0;
    var Name = "";
    function onChange(arg) {
        ID = this.dataItem(this.select()).ID;
        Name = this.dataItem(this.select()).Name;

        $('#ChildGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        $('#ChildGrid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
    }
    function GetData() {
        return {
            ID: ID,
            Name: Name
        };
    }
</script>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult GetChildData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int ID, string Name)
{
    List<ChildModel> lst = new List<ChildModel>();

    if (ID == 0)
    {
        return Json(lst.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

    string str = ":" + ID + "_" + Name;


    lst.Add(new ChildModel() { ChildID = 1, ChildName = "Name1" + str });
    lst.Add(new ChildModel() { ChildID = 2, ChildName = "Name2" + str });
    lst.Add(new ChildModel() { ChildID = 3, ChildName = "Name3" + str });

    return Json(lst.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}

public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    List<TestModel> lst = new List<TestModel>();
    lst.Add(new TestModel() { ID = 1, Name = "Name1", MyDate = DateTime.Now });
    lst.Add(new TestModel() { ID = 2, Name = "Name2", MyDate = DateTime.Now });
    lst.Add(new TestModel() { ID = 3, Name = "Name3", MyDate = DateTime.Now });

    return Json(lst.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

**MODEL**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildModel
    {
        public int ChildID { get; set; }
        public string ChildName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Hi, will this result only selected item in the first grid right? but I want all the results (It will be more than one) (I don't want to select manually) from the first grid to be sent to action method of bind to second grid. can you change it accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like that in my project. I've searched a lot and I finally realize that the solution is creating master and detail grids, the first gird will be the master and the second which get information from the first is detail, in my example is have two grid, one for Sport Branch and the other is for Federation. Federation get information from Sport Branch.

**The Sport Branch grid:**

```
<div >
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SportBranchViewModel>()
              .Name("grid")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(p => p.SportBranchTitle).Title("Title").Width(120);
                  columns.Command(command =>  {  command.Edit().Text("Edit").UpdateText("OK").CancelText("Cancel");
                      command.Destroy().Text("Delete");
                  })
                      .Width(172);
              })
              .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Create"))
              .Editable(editable =>
              {
                  editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine);
                  editable.DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Are you sure you want to delete");
              })
              .Scrollable()
              .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(true))
              .ClientDetailTemplateId("federationtemplate")
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()

                  .Events(events => events.Error("onError"))
                  .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.SportBranchID))
                  .Read(read => read.Action("SportBranch_Read", "BaseData"))
                  .Update(update => update.Action("SportBranch_Update", "BaseData"))
                  .Create(create => create.Action("SportBranch_Create", "BaseData"))
                  .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteSportBranch", "BaseData"))
                      )
                .Events(events => events.DataBound("collapseGrid"))
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:400px;" }))


</div>
```

**the Federation grid:**

```
<script id="federationtemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SportBranchFederationViewModel>()
                                          .Name("grid_#=SportBranchID#")
                          .Columns(columns =>
                          {                   
                              columns.Bound(p => p.FederationName).Title("Title").Width(200);
                              columns.Command(command =>
                              {
                                  command.Edit().Text("Edit").UpdateText("OK").CancelText("Cancel");
                                      command.Destroy().Text("Delete");
                              })
                                  ;
                          })
                          .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                                {
                                        toolbar.Create().Text("Create");
                                }
                            )
                          .Editable(editable =>
                          {
                              editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine);
                              editable.DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Are you sure you want to delete?");
                          })
                          .Scrollable()
                          .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(true))
                          .Pageable()
                          .Events( e=> e.DataBound("onDataBoundFederation"))

                          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                              .Ajax()
                              .Events(events => events.Error("onError"))
                                      .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.FederationID))
                                      .Read(read => read.Action("SportBranchFederation_Read", "BaseData", new { sportBranchID = "#=SportBranchID#" }))
                                      .Create(create => create.Action("SportBranchFederation_Add", "BaseData", new { sportBranchID  = "#=SportBranchID#" }))
                                      .Update(update => update.Action("SportBranchFederation_Update", "BaseData", new { sportBranchID = "#=SportBranchID#" }))
                                      .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("SportBranchFederation_Destroy", "BaseData", new { sportBranchID = "#=SportBranchID#" }))
                            .PageSize(7)
                          )
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:250px;" })
                          .ToClientTemplate()
                )

       </script>
```

**in the controller:**

```
public ActionResult SportBranchFederation_Read(int sportBranchID , [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
            {
                var data = _bvaDataService.GetFederations(sportBranchID);

                return Json(CreateSportBranchFederationsFromFederations(data.ToList()).ToDataSourceResult(request));
            }
```

### Here is the steps:

1. put the second grid in a script tag and specify an id for the script tag.
2. In the first grid use the `ClientDetailTemplateId()` and pass the id of script tag which enclose the second grid.
3. In the action of second grid which you want pass the value of a column of the first gird use the expression "#= [column's name of the first grid]#" (here is `"#=SportBranchID#"`). Note the "#= #" can use in grid to use a value of a field from the current grid or another. I send this field to my read action to get the corresponding result( look at my controller)
4. adding `ToClientTemplate()` to the second grid

read these samples too :
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate  , 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/detailtemplate